# Compare largest number among a list of XML input parse using Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, numbers, compare

```
   Set node = xmldoc.SelectNodes("//Attribute[@name='XSHIP_LOCATION']")
   For Each n In node
        result = n.Text
        logmsg = "XSHIP_LOCATION: " & result
        Call PrintLog(logmsg, logline)
   Next n
```

For every line in xml that contains name=XSHIP_LOCATION, the value of that attribute will be read. How can i compare the list of results read from XML and pick the highest number?

Example of result = 1, 2,1,3,5,4,1,2

I would like to find the largest number from the list of inputs read from XML which is 5 in this case using .

Can anyone kind enough to help this newbie? Thanks

Comment: i'm wondering if there's a more efficient way beside assigning the default value and compare the default value with each incoming xml input and reassign the max value after comparison

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not add a second variable to capture the maximum value, then each iteration through the loop, compare the maximum to the result.... as such

```
    result = n.Text   '->your code
    if result > max then max = result
    logmsg = "XSHIP_LOCATION: " & result    '--> your code
```

Note that if n is NOT a number, this will throw an error.